# myVar.src Is not setting my image src

Tags: javascript, html, image, function

I'm making a website with a modal portfolio, but i just want the full sized images to load on the page after I click it. The modal itself is working fine, but every image loads at once when the page is opened.

I've come up with a solution, but i can't get my modalImg.src work. It sets it's value to what i need, but on the webpage it doesn't really work.

```js
function imgClicked(imgId){

   var modal = document.getElementById("myModal" + imgId);
   var modalImg = "m" + imgId
   
   modal.style.display = "block";
   modalImg.src = "img/port0" + imgId + ".png";
   
   var span = document.getElementById("close" + imgId);
   
   span.onclick = function() { 
    modal.style.display = "none";
   }
  }
```

```html
<div class="item"><img src="img/mobile/port001.png" class="imgequipe" id="01" onClick="imgClicked(this.id)"></div>
  <div id="myModal01" class="modal">
    <span class="close" id="close01">&times;</span>
    <img class="modal-content" id="m01">
  </div>
```

If I set and alert to show me the variable `modalImg`, it's set to the value I want, but it doesn't really change the image `src` attribute.

---

SOLVED - My problem is that I was setting a String variable, so I declared

```
modalImg = document.getElementById("m" + imgId);
```

and it worked.

Comment: Where are you doing the change of the attribute with `modal`? `modalImg` seems to be a String object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really know what `modalImg` is meant to do, but you have the DOM image object stored in the variable `modal`. So what you need to do is to set `.src` on `modal`, instead of `modalImg`. Probably a typo.

```
modal.src = "img/port0" + imgId + ".png";
```

*Edit; Problem solved in comments.*

Comment: The modal is actually a container that is set to display: none. When you click in the img, the js sets it to display: block, and adds the full sized image to it. The modalImg var, is the one that receives the id of the full sized image.

Comment: It's definitely not visible in the code you provided. The variable modalImg is a String of `"m" + imgId`..

Comment: So this must be why it doesn't set my src to the value i want? Because it's a String?

Comment: Ok, that was my problem. I did this var modalImg = document.getElementById("m" + imgId); 

And now it works. Thanks man!